# Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\MyOrders::setOrderstatus() must be an instance of App\Entity\OrderStatus or null, integer given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Please i am new to symfony and i am trying to save a reference id to a table but getting these error "Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\MyOrders::setOrderstatus() must be an instance of App\Entity\OrderStatus or null, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphonycrud\src\Repository\MyOrdersRepository.php on line 69"
Kindly not that this code is base on symfony 5+, I have tried a lot of option but to no avail.
Thanks in advance.

i have a **MyOrders** Entity

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MyOrdersRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MyOrdersRepository::class)
 */
class MyOrders
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $order_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $order_total;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $order_discount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $order_items;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shipping_details;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=OrderStatus::class, inversedBy="myOrders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderstatus;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrderCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->order_code;
    }

    public function setOrderCode(string $order_code): self
    {
        $this->order_code = $order_code;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrderTotal(): ?string
    {
        return $this->order_total;
    }

    public function setOrderTotal(string $order_total): self
    {
        $this->order_total = $order_total;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrderDiscount(): ?string
    {
        return $this->order_discount;
    }

    public function setOrderDiscount(string $order_discount): self
    {
        $this->order_discount = $order_discount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrderItems(): ?string
    {
        return $this->order_items;
    }

    public function setOrderItems(string $order_items): self
    {
        $this->order_items = $order_items;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShippingDetails(): ?string
    {
        return $this->shipping_details;
    }

    public function setShippingDetails(string $shipping_details): self
    {
        $this->shipping_details = $shipping_details;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrderstatus(): ?OrderStatus
    {
        return $this->orderstatus;
    }

    public function setOrderstatus(?OrderStatus $orderstatus): self
    {
        $this->orderstatus = $orderstatus;

        return $this;
    }

  


}
```

my second entity is **OrderStatus**

```
 namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\OrderStatusRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderStatusRepository::class)
 */
class OrderStatus
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $statusdescription;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MyOrders::class, mappedBy="orderstatus")
     */
    private $myOrders;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myOrders = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   
  
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

public function getStatusdescription(): ?string
{
    return $this->statusdescription;
}

public function setStatusdescription(string $statusdescription): self
{
    $this->statusdescription = $statusdescription;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * @return Collection|MyOrders[]
 */
public function getMyOrders(): Collection
{
    return $this->myOrders;
}

public function addMyOrder(MyOrders $myOrder): self
{
    if (!$this->myOrders->contains($myOrder)) {
        $this->myOrders[] = $myOrder;
        $myOrder->setOrderstatus($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeMyOrder(MyOrders $myOrder): self
{
    if ($this->myOrders->removeElement($myOrder)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($myOrder->getOrderstatus() === $this) {
            $myOrder->setOrderstatus(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->statusdescription;
}
 

}
```

This is my Repository **MyordersRepository**

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\MyOrders;
use App\Entity\OrderStatus;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

/**
 * @method MyOrders|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method MyOrders|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method MyOrders[]    findAll()
 * @method MyOrders[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class MyOrdersRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    private $manager;
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, MyOrders::class);
        parent::__construct($registry, OrderStatus::class);
        $this->manager=$manager;
       
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return MyOrders[] Returns an array of MyOrders objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->andWhere('m.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?MyOrders
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->andWhere('m.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    
    public function createorder($order_code,$order_total,$order_discount,$order_items,$shipping_details,$order_status)
    {
        //$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $neworders=new MyOrders();
        //$os=new OrderStatus();
        $neworders
        ->setOrderCode($order_code)
        ->setOrderTotal($order_total)
        ->setOrderDiscount($order_discount)
        ->setOrderItems($order_items)
        ->setShippingDetails($shipping_details)
        ->setOrderstatus($order_status);

        $this->manager->persist($neworders);
        //$this->manager->persist($os);

        $this->manager->flush();
    }
```

This is my Controller **MyOrdersController**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/orderss",methods={"GET"})
 */
public function orderss(EntityManagerInterface $em,Request $request)//: JsonResponse
{
    //$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $OrderStatus=new OrderStatus();
    //$orders = new MyOrders();
    $orderstatusss=$em->getRepository(OrderStatus::class)->findAll(['myOrders'=>$this->getUser()->getId()]);
    //$orderstatusss=$em->getRepository(OrderStatus::class)->findAll();
    //return new Response(array('hello'=>$orderstatusss));
    $as = $orderstatusss['0'];
    //dump();
  
    
    //die();
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order_code='003';
    $order_total=500;
    $order_discount='0';
    $order_items='dresss';
    $shipping_details='test shipping';
    $order_status=(8);
    //$entityManager->persist($order_status);
    $this->myordersrepository->createorder($order_code,$order_total,$order_discount,$order_items,$shipping_details,$order_status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not symfony issue, you specified in your method setOrderstatus that only OrderStatus object or null can be passed as argument, but you are passing integer there so if you want to load object you need to either load order status from DB by

```
$this->manager->getRepository(OrderStatus::class)->find($order_status);
```

or since you don't need all the data from that Entity you can create just [reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies).
So your create function would look something like this

```
    public function createorder($order_code,$order_total,$order_discount,$order_items,$shipping_details,$order_status)
{
    //$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $neworders=new MyOrders();
    //$os=new OrderStatus();
    $neworders
    ->setOrderCode($order_code)
    ->setOrderTotal($order_total)
    ->setOrderDiscount($order_discount)
    ->setOrderItems($order_items)
    ->setShippingDetails($shipping_details)
    ->setOrderstatus($this->manager->getReference(OrderStatus::class, $order_status));

    $this->manager->persist($neworders);
    //$this->manager->persist($os);

    $this->manager->flush();
}
```